# Do I need to write my own PID controller when using ros2_control?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, while using forward_controller in ros2_control I found:

There is no PID control code involved in ros2_control_demo. I think this is because ros2_control_demo is built on virtual hardware, for example, it handles the relationship between hw_state and hw_command like this:

```
hardware_interface::return_type RRBotSystemPositionOnlyHardware::read()
{
  RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("RRBotSystemPositionOnlyHardware"), "Reading...");

  for (uint i = 0; i < hw_states_.size(); i++)
  {
    // Simulate RRBot's movement
    hw_states_[i] = hw_states_[i] + (hw_commands_[i] - hw_states_[i]) / hw_slowdown_;
    RCLCPP_INFO(
      rclcpp::get_logger("RRBotSystemPositionOnlyHardware"), "Got state %.5f for joint %d!",
      hw_states_[i], i);
  }
  RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("RRBotSystemPositionOnlyHardware"), "Joints successfully read!");

  return hardware_interface::return_type::OK;
}
```

Does that mean I need to write my own PID control code if using real hardware?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/395815/do-i-need-to-write-my-own-pid-controller-when-using-ros2_control?/) by [Tudala](https://answers.ros.org/users/92097/tudala/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ros2 controls isn't opinionated on how your hardware interface is implemented. Some hardware may have it's own PID control already. You don't have to implement your own PID though, there are many useful control classes in the [ros2 control_toolbox package](https://github.com/ros-controls/control_toolbox.git) on github, or install via `sudo apt install ros-<foxy|galactic>-control-toolbox`.

See the PID class in include/control_toolbox/pid.hpp. There is also a Ros2 PID node that wraps this class, but for ros2_controls implementation you want the one in pid.hpp. I'd peruse the other classes in that package as well.

---

Originally posted by [guru_florida](https://answers.ros.org/users/49713/guru_florida/) with karma: 280 on 2022-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2